# Passing PHP Variables to JS using Localize Script

Tags: php, javascript, wp-localize-script

Im trying to pass some variables (author of the post, category of the post, and title of the post) to a js file using wp_localize_script.

I cannot, for the life of me get these correct. How can I pull this data about the current post that is being viewed?

Current code:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'stats', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/t5-demo.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

$categories = implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( get_the_category( get_the_ID() ), 'name' ) ); 
$datatoBePassed = array(
    'author' =>  get_queried_object()->post_author,
    'category'   => $categories,
    'title'      => single_post_title( '', false )
);
wp_localize_script( 'stats', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed );
```

Below is an example of what does work (just sticking static numbers in), so I believe it has something to do with how im trying to pull those variables about the post that is being viewed..

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'stats', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/t5-demo.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

    $categories = implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( get_the_category( get_the_ID() ), 'name' ) ); 
    $datatoBePassed = array(
        'author' =>  '10',
        'category'   => '11',
        'title'      => '12'
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'stats', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed );
```

Comment: I this in the admin or on the front end.  Also, this code should be in an action, either `admin_init` on the admin side or `wp_enqueue_scripts` if its on the front end.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: font end — it is in an enqueue script (see first line..)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the post isn't ready yet in that action

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in an action callback function:

```
function wpse186202_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'stats', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/t5-demo.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

    $categories = implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( get_the_category( get_the_ID() ), 'name' ) ); 
    $datatoBePassed = array(
        'author' =>  get_queried_object()->post_author,
        'category'   => $categories,
        'title'      => single_post_title( '', false )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'stats', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse186202_enqueue_scripts' ); //Front end enqueueing
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse186202_enqueue_scripts' ); //Admin enqueueing
```

The action will call the function at the right moment for it to be enqueued properly.  Choose the one that works for where you want it enqueued.

Comment: see updated question.. there is no bug in the function itself (its working with static numbers), just in how im trying to pull those variables?